# In a bipartite system $AB$, why does the entanglement negativity $\mathcal{N}(\rho^{T_A})$ measure the entanglement between $A$ and $B$?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, density-matrix, partial-transpose, entanglement-negativity

Consider a system composed of two subsystems $A$ and $B$ living in $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$. The density matrix of the system $AB$ is defined to be $\rho$. The entanglement negativity of $\rho$, defined as
$$\mathcal{N}_A(\rho) := \frac12(\|\rho^{T_A}\|_1 -1),$$ where $\rho^{T_A}$ is the partial transposition of $\rho$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the trace norm, measures by how much $\rho^{T_A}$ fails to be positive semidefinite. This is useful since would $\rho$ be separable, $\rho^{T_A}$ would be positive semidefinite, hence $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)=0$. This, along with some other nice properties makes $\mathcal{N}$ a nice entanglement measure.

**I have read that if $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)\neq 0$ then one can claim $A$ is entangled with $B$. This is what I don’t understand. By definition, $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)$ measures by how much $\rho^{T_A}$ fails to be positive semidefinite, an essential property of a separable and hence a non-entangled system. Great, we know whether $\rho$ is entangled or not. However, just because we are told $\rho$ is entangled it doesn’t necessarily mean that the degrees of freedom in $A$ are entangled with those in $B$ right? I guess my problem could steem from the fact that I don’t understand the physical consequences of taking a partial transpose of $\rho$ w.r.t. some subsystem (i.e. what is the physical significance of $\rho^{T_A}$?).**

Edit: First of all for your all your comments and generous patience. I edited the question to better address my last issue with understanding entanglement negativity.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. $\rho$ is your quantum state, you want the entanglement negativity of $\rho$, not the entanglement negativity of $\rho^{T_A}$.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to make explicit that $\mathcal{N}$ depends on the choice of over which subsytem the partial transpose is being performed on. In general, $\mathcal{N}(\rho^{T_A})\neq \mathcal{N}(\rho^{T_{A'}})$ when $A\neq A'$.

Comment: This is not true, $\mathcal N$ is the same independently of whether you transpose on A or B, because $\rho^{T_A}$ has the same eigenvalues of $\rho^{T_B}$. And even if it were true, the best way would be to write something like $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)$, because your variable is still $\rho$.

Comment: Im not saying that. I am saying that the negativity depends on your definition of subsystems. $\rho$ exists without the need of $A$ or $B$ so $\mathcal{N}(\rho)$ to me is ambiguous as it depends on how you partition the system. I also like your notation of $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)$, I will edit that.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian You would expect that any meaningful measure of entanglement would depend on how you partition the whole system into subsystems.

Comment: @Rammus Indeed, but why if $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)\neq 0$ then $A$ is entangled with $B$?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Because all separable states for that bipartition would satisfy $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho) = 0$, if we find that it is non-zero then it cannot be the case that $\rho$ is separable, hence it is entangled. Note that there are PPT states that are entangled so this doesn't capture the entanglement of all states.

Comment: @Rammus Maybe it helps if I put an example of my question. Say $AB$ is some spin chain and $A$ and $B$ are some selection of spins such that “$A+B=AB$”. If I vary the size of $A$ and $B$ but keeping $AB$ fixed, $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)$ will vary accordingly, from being zero when $A=AB$ and $B= \emptyset$ to perhaps a non zero value for other choices of $A$ and $B$. Suppose for some particular choice of $A$ and $B$ we find $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)\neq 0$. What is it specific about $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)$ that tells us that it is $A$ and $B$ and not any other parts that are the ones entangled?

Comment: If $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho) \neq 0$ then it tells you that for that particular partition, the state is entangled. It does not say anything about whether the state is entangled under other partitions. Note that `entanglement' is defined with respect to a chosen partition. You ask is my state separable with respect to this chosen partition, if not then it's entangled. I'm not really understanding what the problem is.

Comment: @Rammus Okay good, so in which step is clear that the mathematics “know” that we have chosen $A$ and $B$ fixed? Because to me, so far, $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho)$ is just a mathematical trick to study the separability (or positive semidefiniteness) of some object “$\rho^{T_A}$”. This is at most interesting, but I fail to see how this object $\rho^{T_A}$ knows anything about the way we have partitioned the system, sure the partial transpose is w.r.t. $A$, so what?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian How do you take the partial transpose without knowing what partition you have chosen?

Comment: I have edited my question and I believe it now addresses my issue better.

Comment: @Rammus , When you say “If $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho) \neq 0$ then […] is entangled”, do you mean the partition $AB$ is entangled or the partition $B$ is entangled with the partition $A$? If the latter, why if $\rho^{T_A}$ fails to be positive semidefinite then it follows that $A$ is entangled with $B$? (I don’t understand the physical significance of $\rho \mapsto \rho^{T_A}$)

Answer (score 4):

There is no good definition of what is an "amount of entanglement". We have some requirements, such as saying that a measure of entanglement must be convex and cannot increase under local operations, but beyond that it is really a matter of taste.

There is a nice interpretation of entanglement negativity, though, in the case that $\rho^{T_A}$ only has a single negative eigenvalue. Let it be $-\lambda$. Then by construction $\mathcal N(\rho) = \lambda$, and $d\mathcal N(\rho)$ almost coincides with the amount of white noise you must add to $\rho$ before it becomes separable.

This is another measure of entanglement, called random robustness, defined more precisely as $R(\rho)$ being the minimal $s \ge 0$ such that the state
$$\rho' = \frac1{1+s}(\rho + s I/d)$$
is separable.

I'm saying almost because $\rho^{T_A} \ge 0$ in general does not imply that $\rho$ is separable. But in the cases when it does, $R(\rho)$ is the minimal $s$ such that
$${\rho'}^{T_A} = \frac1{1+s}(\rho^{T_A} + s I/d) \ge 0,$$ which is precisely $d\lambda$.

More generally, I don't know any nice interpretation for entanglement negativity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don’t understand why if $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho) \neq 0$ then subsystem $A$ is entangled with $B$.

Comment: As a side comment, is it possible to come up with a definition of entanglement so useful and universal that renders the rest of entanglement definitions pointless? Or will we always have to wisely choose our weapons? (This question is purposely vague)

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian It's basic logic: ($\rho$ is separable $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal{N}_A(\rho) = 0$) is equivalent to ($\mathcal{N}_A(\rho) \neq  0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rho$ is not separable, i.e. entangled).

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich I see that, $\rho$ is entangled. But I cannot see that within $\rho$ it is the degrees of freedom in $A$ the ones entangled with those in $B$. Cause we could find upon partial trace to $A$ that $A$ is unentangled whereas $B$ is entangled, right?

Comment: Just a side comment: negativity is a "nice" measure of entanglement because it is *computable* and not so much for its operational interpretation; we already have measures of entanglement that have clear operational meaning (in the asymptotic scenario) such as distillable entanglement, entanglement of formation, etc.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian if I understand your last comment: yes, you can equivalently define it using $\mathcal N_B$ rather than $\mathcal N_A$. Entanglement is a property of the bipartite system, not of one of its components

Comment: @keisuke.akira: you mean *easily* computable. All measures of entanglement that I'm aware of are computable in the sense of there existing an algorithm that can provide an $\epsilon$ approximation to them. It's just that usually the complexity is horrifying, but for negativity it is polynomial in the dimension of the state.

Comment: @MateusAraújo Yes, that's what I meant :)

Comment: I have edited my question and I believe it now addresses my issue better.

Comment: @Mateus *"All measures of entanglement that I'm aware of are computable in the sense of there existing an algorithm that can provide an ϵ approximation to them."* -- This is not true (afaik) for quantities defined in the limit of many copies (distillable entanglement, entanglement cost,...), which arguably from the conceptual point are the best definitions. Neither for e.g. sqashed entanglement.

Comment: See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5425

Comment: That's a good point, the asymptotic measures might very well be uncomputable, I completely forgot about them.